# Can I release a no longer needed property of an instance of an object without worrying that dealloc will later "over-release" it?

Tags: objective-c

I have an instance of an object "myObject" that has a few UIImage objects as properties. After I access these properties the first time I really don't need them any more.

Can I do a release on the instance's UIImage properties before the instance itself is released, or will this over-release the UIImage properties later when the "myObject" dealloc releases them also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time you release an variable that is still in scope, you should immediately set it to nil. This will avoid the problem you're discussing in `-dealloc`. The best way to achieve this is to always use accessors. If you use accessors, then calling `self.foo=nil` will take care of everything for you.

Comment: I am using accessors. So I just do "myObject.someImage = nil" to free memory and leave the object's dealloc do the release as usual? 

If I've got that right it seems easy enough. Thanks!!

Comment: Yep that's the recommended way. The accessor will do nothing if the variable is already nil, and will call release on the object otherwise.